# How to made model popup open after server side form validation in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

How to made model popup open after server side form validation in codeigniter

// calling modal popup

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#register">REGISTER </a>
```

//This is my modal popup

```
<div id="register" class="modal fade">

<form method="POST" action="">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name">
<span class="red"><?php echo form_error('name'); ?></span>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
Close
</button>
<button type="submit" name="sub_customer" value="save" class="btn btn-primary">
Save
</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="add_register_popup"></div>


<a onclick="ajax_register_popup();">REGISTER </a>

function ajax_register_popup ()
{
       $.ajax
       ({
         url: "<?php echo "your url of your register view page "?>/",
         success: function (data)
         {
            $('#add_register_popup').html(data);
            $('#add_register_popup').modal({
                backdrop: 'static',
                keyboard: false
            });
         }
     });
 }
```

try like this , first make function and bind that view in popup div like i did , and then make onclick to trigger that function and use the main modal div for your popup view called and bind by #add_register_popup id . try it ,sure  it helps you .

Comment: remove the data-toggle="modal" data-target="#register" from your link

Comment: I am not using ajax to save

Comment: this is not for save , only open a modal popup for validation